# Can't type password when I want to push file to github

Tags: git, github, command-line

I am new to Git and GitHub. I followed what google told me about how to push file to GitHub, starts from making the file itself, using git add and then commit,  and then when I type git push origin master, it asked me to type username and password. It's okay with username, I can type it but not with password. What's happened?

Answer (score 4):

When you type the password the cursor won't move on the command-line. Type the password, then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

My password had numbers in it and I discovered that it would give me an error message when I entered the numbers using the keypad, but it worked perfectly when I used the numbers at the top of the keyboard instead.